# OSX unexpectedly forwarding localhost requests to a domain

Tags: laravel, macos, docker, apache

I'm scratching my head at this:

I've got a fresh laravel app which I'm developing using `php artisan serve` on `127.0.0.1:8000`. The OS is OSX Big Sur. (important for later: docker is not running on my machine.)

There are relative image paths being used in the app, the images do exist in file system.

Some (not all) images are 404ing, because the app is trying to retrieve them from a domain I used to develop on a docker container - this was a separate app and last used months ago.

E.G. a hardcoded relative image path `/media/image.jpeg` will show in the network log as 404 with the URL being: `https://www.example.com/media/image.jpeg` Not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image.jpeg` which would be the expected behaviour.

- This happens in both Chrome and Safari, leading me to think it is not
  a caching issue, though I have cleared caches in both browsers.
- There is no mention of `https://www.example.co.uk` in `/etc/hosts`
- There is no mention of `https://www.example.co.uk` in `.htaccess`
- There is no forced SSL in the application.  Apache is not being used
  to serve the app, but Apache was used in the docker container
  which    ran `https://www.example.co.uk`.
- Same behaviour when serving app on `php artisan serve --host=derp.com` in stead of `127.0.0.1`

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: maybe it's in your hosts file?

Comment: Good suggestion but there's no mention of https://www.example.co.uk in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Damnit.

Somehow, a view file had a meta tag of: `<base href="https://www.example.co.uk/" />` and was causing all relative assets to go to that domain, so this wasn't an environmental issue.